# Select Count on multiple tables in one query

Tags: t-sql

Can someone help me with this TSQL syntax? I am trying to do

```
Select Count(Distinct Value) AS OpenPO
FROM OpenPOs

AND 


Select Count(Distinct Value) As OpenSho
From OpenSho
```

etc.

How do I make this into one neat query with results like its all part of a single table or view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT (Select Count(Distinct Value) FROM OpenPOs) AS OpenPO,
       (Select Count(Distinct Value) From OpenSho) AS OpenSho
```

You will get as result something like:

```
OpenPO  OpenSho
---------------
3       5
```